# Jquery convert object to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert object into a string inside the Jquery? Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var str = $(this).find("text");

      alert(str);  

       }
    });
</script
```

Result of alert(str) is object Object. It will not display the text element. What's the problem with my code? Thanks

Comment: Which element do you want to find?

Comment: Two problems. 1. `text` is not an element. 2. `alert` is not for debugging code.

Comment: Try: `var str = $(this).text();` This might display all text of the page... or alternatively you can try this: `alert(str.text());` Don't know why you're not using css selectors for your `$(this).find` cause `$(this).find` is looking for "text" in all of the document. You should use selectors similar to: `$('#target').text();`

Comment: Object to String? `JSON.stringify()`, but it's not backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. Because text is not an element and also you cannot alert objects.

The right code would be:
HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello WOrld</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
alert($("div").find("p").text());
```

### [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y467sa6e/1/)

Comment: Hello @faiz. I would like to ask, how would I able to display the value of var str(stated above) using jquery?

Comment: you can't because thats not a dom object

Comment: Well in order to see the objects you can use `console.log(anyObject)` function.

Comment: And see for the javascript console. That is built in for chrome.